# How many IP camera video feeds can jetson nano simultaneously process for object detection

Tags: video-streaming, object-detection, frame-rate, ip-camera, nvidia-jetson-nano

How many incoming video feeds can Jetson Nano process simultaneously for people counting and object detection.
Lets say I have 4 IP Camera, 2 camera feeds i need to do object detection and on other 2 I want to get people count.
Do I need 4 nos of Jetson nano or can I use 1 board to process all 4 feeds.

Answer (score 0):

The jetson nano will do the job. The [DeepStream SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/deepstream-sdk) will allow you to optimize your video pipeline. It also provide pre-trained models and the `Jetpack 4.4` comes with `TensorRT`. You should have no issue in running 4 cameras. You can use the same model for the 4 streams achieving detection, tracking (and counting).
Here is the installation[DS installation guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/deepstream/dev-guide/index.html). You can play with the samples to run multiple streams. It's impressive for a little board.